# Получить значение после изменения стейта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, setstate

У меня есть стейт предположим:

```js
const [ fields, setFields ] = useState(
    {
        field1: { error: "" },
        field2: { error: "" },
        field3: { error: "" }
    }
);
```

Мне его нужно изменить (в моем случае это валидация) и следом проверить значения, абстрактный код:

```js
const onFormSubmit: (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void = (event) =>
{
    event.preventDefault()

    // делаем какую-то валидацию
    setFields((prevState) => (
        {
            ...prevState,
            field1:
            {
                ...prevState[ prevState ],
                error: "Test"
            }
        }
    ));

    // Если у нас есть ошибки, мы не выполняем дальше код
    if (fields.field1.error !== "")
    {
        // какой-то код
        return;
    }

    console.info("submit");
}
```

У меня не заходит в блок с `if`, я понимаю, что реакт это делает асинхронно, но как мне увидеть изменения в этом же блоке?

Comment: используйте [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) в теле компонента. setState - асинхронный, и в тот момент, когда у вас отрабатывает `if`, ваше состояние еще не изменилось.

Comment: Но мне нужно провалидировать и только после этого отправить форму, немного не представляю как тут поможет useEffect ибо он будет следить за изменением объекта и срабатывать без кнопки.

Comment: У вас есть `onFormSubmit`, всё, что он должен знать - валидна или нет форма, если да, то отправить (Как вариант, это можно сделать через useEffect, если поля валидны, то делать кнопку submit активной). Прикрепите весь компонент, чтобы было понятно, как вы используете onFormSubmit.

Comment: `onFormSubmit` указан в `<form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>` и кнопка имеет `type="submit"`.

Comment: Что вам мешает выполнить валидацию и записывать ошибки в state только, если они есть?  `if (error) {setState(()=>{})} else {console.info("submit")}`

Comment: Не удобно и много кода получится.

Comment: Тогда предварительно сохраните ошибку в переменную внутри функции `onChangeHandler`, эту же переменную используйте в `if`

Comment: Я не использую в onChange ничего кроме записи `value` в тот же `fields`.

Comment: Ошибся, речь шла о `onFormSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть 2 варианта.

1. Использовать классовый компонент, в котором ф-я обновления состояния `this.setState` принимает 2 аргумента, 1 - новое состояние, 2 - коллбек ф-ю, которая будет вызвана после обновления состояния (см. пример ниже)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    }
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState(({
      value
    }) => ({
      value: value + 1
    }), () => {
      //сделать что-то, после обновления стейта
      console.log('State updated ' + this.state.value)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick = {
      this.increment.bind(this)
    } > {
      this.state.value
    } < /button>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

2. Использовать хук `useEffect` в функциональном компоненте

```js
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //Чтобы не выполнять при первом рендере можно исключить состояние инициализации
    const isFirstRender = !value
    if (!isFirstRender) {
      //сделать что-то после обновления value
      console.log('Value is Updated: ' + value)
    }
  }, [value])

  return <button onClick = {
    () => setValue((prev) => prev + 1)
  } > {
    value
  } < /button>
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```